# Unable to render html file using Route in react

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render html using Route but browser is giving me following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/hello.html 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You
>   may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>
> > `<html> |   Hello | </html>`

I have already tried using babel but when I run `npm start` the terminal is telling me undo all the babel and webpack changes -

> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "babel-loader" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>      In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.          If this
>      has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead. This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /Users/shubhamnandanwar/Desktop/react/YourHourWebApp/node_modules/babel-loader is outside your project directory. For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls babel-loader in your project folder. This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-loader.

This is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import UserStory from "./components/stories/UserStory";
import SignIn from "./components/auth/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./components/auth/SignUp";
import CreateStory from "./components/stories/CreateStory";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  reload = () => window.location.reload();

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={TemplateHTMLComponent} />
            <Route exact path="/stories" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/story/:id" component={UserStory} />
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/uploadStory" component={CreateStory} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

class TemplateHTMLComponent extends React.Component {
  htmlFile = require("./hello.html");
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.htmlFile }} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am new in react and have spent hours trying to fix it. Can anyone please give me some direction

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all install `html-loader` module.

`npm install --save-dev html-loader`

2) Inside `webpack.config.js`

```
{
  modules: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' }
    ]
  }
}
```

3) Correct the calling component

```
import htmlFile from './hello.html';

class TemplateHTMLComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.htmlFile }} />;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Hey @tarzenchugh, I had tried installing webpack but react had told me to revert all the webpack changes. Can you direct how should i install webpack? Is it possible to directly add webpack.config.js file without installing webpack?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? Which bundler are you using if not using webpack?

Comment: I am not sure what bundler is but I guess I am using npm

Comment: npm is package manager. how did you create your application was it using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yup.. i had used create-react-app

Comment: I am able to run it correctly using `create-react-app`.`create-react-app` already uses webpack, so you don't need to install it. See [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-goldstine-x71ip) for working code.

Comment: but i can't see webpack.config.js file.. do you have any clue?

Comment: are you talking about webpack.config.js which is in node-modules>react-scripts>config directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199282/discussion-between-tarzen-chugh-and-shubh).

Answer (score 0):

please put 'htmlFile = require("./hello.html");' line on the top outside the class.

```
const htmlFile = require("./hello.html");

class TemplateHTMLComponent extends React.Component {      
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.htmlFile }} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the webpack.config.js and package.json file to your question. It look likes some config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your html is a string. Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Then export it from a .js file like this:

```
// inside hello.js file
// using es6 syntax
export default `<html> |   Hello | </html>`
```

or

```
// inside hello.js file
// using older syntax
module.exports = `<html>blah blah</html>`
```

then import it:

```
import htmlFile from 'htmlFile'
```

or

```
const htmlFile = require('hello')
```